# Moodle sql query to get the report of completed as well as not completed list of enrolled users

Tags: sql, report, moodle

I am using a Moodle ad-hoc query to fetch the report data I want to generate a completion report. The report is a list of all the enrolled users with course completion status.

I have tried the query below but it's only giving the list of the users who have completed the course. It's not showing the enrolled users who have not completed the course, which is needed in my report.

```
SELECT u.username, u.firstname,u.lastname,u.email,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%Y-%m-%d') AS 
completed,p.timecompleted
FROM prefix_course_completions AS p
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON p.course = c.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON p.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN prefix_cohort_members AS co ON co.cohortid=u.id
WHERE c.id=361 AND co.cohortid=142
ORDER BY u.username
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found at least part of your issue.

Within your query, you do `INNER JOIN prefix_cohort_members AS co ON co.cohortid=u.id`.  This is joining the cohorts id to the users id, instead of user id to user id.  I believe the correct line is `INNER JOIN prefix_cohort_members AS co ON co.userid=u.id`

Also within your query, you do both `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%Y-%m-%d') AS completed` and `p.timecompleted`, which will both return the time completed. I am not sure if this is what you wanted, but if you want to display the enrolled date this would add that for you

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timeenrolled),'%Y-%m-%d') AS enrolled
```

With these two changes I was able to generate a report with a row containing a bool that shows if the user has completed the course or not using this block:

```
CASE 
when p.timecompleted is null THEN 'False'
ELSE 'True'
END AS completed
```

NOTE: I also did not use an inner join, opting instead for just using JOIN.  I am not sure if this made a difference, but if the changes stated above don't work for you, changing the inner join to just JOIN may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct c.id as courseid,c.fullname,u.id as user_id, u.email,cm.id as moduleid,cm.visible,CASE 
WHEN cm.completion=0 THEN "none"
WHEN cm.completion=1 THEN "manual"
WHEN cm.completion=2 THEN "auto"
END as Completion_method,cmc.* 
FROM prefix_course AS c
JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
JOIN prefix_course_modules cm ON cm.course = c.id
LEFT JOIN prefix_course_modules_completion cmc on cm.id=cmc.coursemoduleid and u.id=cmc.userid
where c.id=1234 and cm.visible<>0 and cm.completion<>0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).